# vi issue in SSH TTYs to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server, ssh, vim

After upgrading my server to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, I can no longer use the vi editor to edit anything in an SSH terminal (I access the server by launching ssh sessions from Cygwin running on Windows). The empty portions of the vi window fill with garbage.

The workaround is to launch an xterm from the server back to my Cygwin/X display. Using vi from within the xterm works fine.

Setting my TERM to vt100/vt220/xterm does not help.

Comment: If you are on Windows, my advice is to use Putty rather then Cygwin. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html Otherwise I am not sure if it is a problem with Windows, Cygwin, or Ubuntu. If you wish to use vi, I highly suggest you install vim-full. Alternately use nano.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm not sure which works better for most people, but I use Cygwin on my Windows system and in its default command prompt (multiple terminal emulators are installed by default) I can run and use vi (via ssh or otherwise) with no problems.

Comment: Depends, you are using more then ssh, so Cygwin is probably a better option. If one is using just ssh, Putty is easy as it is distributed as a binary that runs from a flash drive, so portable and easy, no need for administrative rights.

Comment: what does `file /etc/alternatives/vi` say? What is in the vimrc? Is there anything about `set encoding=utf-8`?